# Search string in many files on HP-UX

Tags: grep, hp-ux, recursive, portability

I need to find which files (they can have space in the filename) of a directory contains a string using only sh and system's commands (Perl is **not** an option).

For a few files, this command works fine:

```
# grep -l word *
file 1
file1
```

But if I have 270k file, I obtain the following error:

```
#  grep -l word *
sh: /usr/bin/grep: The parameter list is too long.
```

In HP-UX, the `xargs` command doesn't have the `-0` option, so I can't use this:

```
# find . -print0 |xargs -0 grep -l
xargs: unknown option: -0
```

Do you know which command I can use?

Answer (score 5):

You could use a variant of your `find` command like this:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l word {} \;
```

Comment: You forgot to write the word to search, so this does not answer the problem, so this should not be the best answer unless Mat correct it. @Gilles answer is better and more complete imho.

Comment: Well spotted. Feel free to suggest edits if you spot typoes like that.

Comment: That's better now :-) Still less complete than Gilles answer but works for everyone.

Answer (score 4):

If your version of HP-UX is recent enough, you can call `find` with the `-exec … +` action. This action does the same job as `xargs` (call a command on multiple matching files at once, without overflowing the command line length limit), but in a reliable way for any file name.

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l word {} +
```

If your version of HP-UX is too old, you might have only `-exec … \;` and not `-exec … +`. The `;` version calls the command on one file at a time, which is a bit slower.

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l word {} \;
```

If your file names don't contain `\"'` or whitespace, then you can use `xargs` without the `-0` option.

```
find . -type f -print | xargs grep -l word
```

Answer (score 0):

For a close POSIX equivalent to `grep -l word ./*` that splits the list of files as need to avoid the `execve()` limit on the size of the arguments, you could do:

```
find -L . ! -name . -prune ! -name '.*' -type f -exec \
  grep -l word /dev/null {} +
```

- `! -name . -prune` is to not recurse into sub-directories
- `-L` in combination with `-type f` is to search in regular files only (after symlink resolution) (a bonus compared to the `grep ... ./*` approach which would look inside any type of file)
- `! -name '.*'` to exclude hidden files as `./*` does
- `/dev/null` to make sure the file name is always printed (another bonus).

A notable difference is that the list of files won't be sorted.